# terraform always want to update the cooldown for my elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform, amazon-elb

I have some terraform setting up an whole environment that included elastic beanstalk.  Originally I had a bunch of things that were causing it to always want to update the EB.  I was able to find solutions to all of them except one.  The cooldown for the asg.
I have this in my aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment...

```
setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "CoolDown"
    value     = "1200"
  }
```

If I comment it out, it won't try to update (leaves it at 1200).  But if I create a new env with the code then I get the default value of 300, which I don't want.

It's clear that aws is not reporting the value that way as the plan has this if I leave that code in...

```
setting.2230766795.namespace: "" => "aws:autoscaling:asg"
setting.2230766795.resource:  "" => ""
setting.2230766795.value:     "" => "1200"
```

Even though it is already at 1200.
Am I missing something or is this a bug with the provider?
Using aws version v2.70.0_x4

Comment: What version of the AWS provider are you using?

Comment: version v2.70.0_x4